# PDFJS Firebase Cloud Functions: certificate has expired

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, pdf.js, pdfjs-dist

I am extracting plain text from pdf documents using PDFJS and the extraction is scheduled using Firebase Cloud Functions. All is good until one fine day I am getting `certificate has expired` from selected pdfs, coming mostly from two domains.

I have checked that those affected domains still have valid SSL, and running the plain text extraction code on local machine works with no problem. Once it is deployed to firebase cloud functions, it throws the `certificate has expired` error.

```
Error
    at BaseExceptionClosure (/srv/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js:666:29)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js:669:2)
    at __w_pdfjs_require__ (/srv/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js:52:30)
    at Object.defineProperty.value (/srv/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js:129:23)
    at __w_pdfjs_require__ (/srv/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js:52:30)
    at pdfjsVersion (/srv/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js:116:18)
    at /srv/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js:119:10
    at webpackUniversalModuleDefinition (/srv/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js:25:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js:32:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/pdf/pdf.js:7:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
  message: 'certificate has expired',
  name: 'UnknownErrorException',
  details: 'UnknownErrorException: certificate has expired' }"
```

Code:

```
const pdfjslib = require('pdfjs-dist');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

module.exports = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    let url = req.query.url

    return extractPlainTextFromPdf(url)
    .then(pb => {
        return res.send(pb)
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
        return res.send("Err occured")
    })
});

function extractPlainTextFromPdf(pdfUrl) {
    let options = setupPdfOptions(pdfUrl)
    return getPlainBody(options)
    .then((plainBody) => plainBody)
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log("Err plainBody", err) //<== Error thrown here
    })
}

async function getPlainBody(options) {
    return getDocument(options)
    .then(doc => extractTexts(doc, doc.numPages))
}

function getDocument(options) {
    var loadingTask = pdfjslib.getDocument(options)
    return loadingTask.promise
    .then((doc) => doc)
}

function setupPdfOptions(url) {
    return {
        url: url,
        httpHeaders: {
            "User-Agent": "MY-USER-AGENT",
        },
    };
}
```

Here's two sample pdf that are facing the above issue.

https://www.nea.gov.sg/docs/default-source/our-services/building-planning/notification-of-new-edition-of-code-of-practice-on-environment-health-(2020-edition).pdf

https://www.nparks.gov.sg/-/media/nparks-real-content/partner-us/developers-architects-and-engineers/circular_2020_0106_nparks.pdf?la=en&hash=F25A74CC8667D5D98EDF3A9C186E235330D228A8

EDIT:

```
//package.json
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log",
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "8"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/functions-framework": "^1.5.1",
    "@google-cloud/vision": "^1.11.0",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.667.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "cheerio": "^1.0.0-rc.3",
    "diff-match-patch": "^1.0.4",
    "firebase-admin": "^8.11.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.6.1",
    "moment": "^2.25.0",
    "nodemailer": "^6.4.6",
    "pdfjs-dist": "^2.3.200",
    "request": "^2.88.2",
    "request-promise": "^4.2.5",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.1.6"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: can you add your package.json?

Comment: @JAHDZP Hi, I've added my `package.json`.

Comment: @JAHDZP any luck?

Comment: I trying to run your code sample but I having this issue, I'm not sure if I missing something, could you upload a functional testing snipet. 

Did you tried with Node.js 10?

```
Error: function terminated. Recommended action: inspect logs for termination reason. Details:
ReadableStream is not defined
```

Comment: @JAHDZP ahhh now that I have tried Nodejs 10, it worked. But why??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Node.JS 8 on cloud functions is deprecated](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/nodejs-8-runtime), I think that some packages like openssl and others are obsolete in Node 8 runtime and cause weird SSL issues,  I experienced this behavior in some vintage linux distros(ubuntu 10.04).

"The Node.js 8 runtime will be deprecated on 2020-06-05. To ensure that your functions are on a supported version of Node.js, migrate them to Node.js 10."